# How to push/create an associative array?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am running a loop of posts and these have four properties I need to associate: title, date, link, location:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if( !in_array( $post->ID, $already_displayed_ids )) {
        array_push( $thisPostid, $post->ID );
        $title = get_the_title();
        $location = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-8');
        $link = get_permalink();
        $contentYear = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-14');
        if ($contentYear >= 0 && $contentYear <= 2019) {
            array_push($yearsArray, $contentYear);
            if (($wp_query->current_post +1) == ($wp_query->post_count)) {
                $yearsArray = array_unique($yearsArray);
                sort($yearsArray);
            }
        }
        array_push( $already_displayed_ids, $post->ID );
    }
endwhile;
```

Basically I am running a loop, I check for non duplicate in `$already_displayed_ids` and I need to associate and push the title, location, date and link of any post I am pushing here `array_push($yearsArray, $contentYear);`

At the moment I am only able to push `$contentYear` but there is not `link`, `title` or `location` associated to the pushed post, I thought of creating an associative array in order to push all the specs I need of each posts. `$contentYear` is a custom field with a date, so I am genertaing a navigation with those values, they are dates. But I need to associate to each date their title, location and link as I currently don't know how to push those specs to associated to the time I am pushing.

Comment: I'm unclear what the question or problem is exactly…!?

Comment: @deceze check the update question if it's any clearer

Comment: No, it's not. You explain what you want to do and you show code that appears to do it. Where's the problem/question/issue?

Comment: @deceze updated again, any better?

Comment: @deceze resolved it, posted my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if( !in_array( $post->ID, $already_displayed_ids )) {
        array_push( $thisPostid, $post->ID );
        $contentYear = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-14');
        if ($contentYear >= 0 && $contentYear <= 2019) {
            array_push($yearsArray, 
                array(
                    'year'=> $contentYear,
                    'link'=> get_permalink(),
                    'location'=> usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-8'),
                    'title'=> get_the_title()
                )
            );
        }
        array_push( $already_displayed_ids, $post->ID );
    }
endwhile;
```

Then I can do `foreach ($yearsArray as $year) {` and `echo $year['title']` etc

Answer (score -1):

As far as im aware there is no direct functionality for getting an associative array from posts.
Here is a snippet of what your asking for:

```
$posts = array();
if (have_post()) :
    while (have_posts()) :
        array_push($posts, 
            Array(
                'id'=>the_ID(),
                'quantity'=>1,
                'size'=>$size,
                'colour'=>$colour
            )
        );
    endwhile;
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $posts[0]; // change 0 index
endif;
```

Please note the above code is not ideal, and you probably should be doing this. Also you may want to be using cookies and not sessions.

Comment: thanks, I thought more of doing it in php something like `$_SESSION["cart"] = array ( 
            $id => array (  
                array ("quantity" => 1, "size" => $size, "colour" => $colour) 
            ) 
        );`

Comment: that would work as well. but note PHP sessions are written to a text file on your server. you shouldn't have any sort of session writing inside of a loop.

Comment: it's just an example I found, never worked with associative arrays, could you elaborate it using that example provided just that I better understand it on my case?

Comment: updated my question with a real case scenario, can we adapt?

Comment: you're changing your question to much, i hope you fine the solution you're looking for.

Comment: ok thanks, tbh the question is the same, I am still looking for an associative array, you weren't too far from resolving it

Comment: ok thank you, your answer helped in finding a solution. Posted my own answer